# Shopify billing api charges for sellers

Tags: shopify

New here and i hope i am in the right place to ask my question. We are having problem with submitting our app to Shopify App Store.

We have an app where people can create their own designs on our physical products and sell. So we can produce their products and dropship to their customers. There are many apps to that.

Problem is they forcing us to use Billing API for our product charges. They take 20% of commission which our margin is not that much. We are wholesaler and we our margin is super low. We use (well we were planing to use) Stripe for products charges, which is 2.9 % commission.

And Shopify Apps Team member is keep asking me my margin, and says: "We are requiring that all apps use the billing API, but I might be able to make an exception since it seems like your business model isn't compatible. If an exception is made, you will be required to sign a revenue share agreement based on your margins"

All other App (in our business line)they charge their customers with 3th party payment processors and i have spoken with some of them they say they never heard about it and they don't share any revenue (apart from membership fees) with Shopify.

Any idea about this?

Thank you so much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify is charging 20% of the cost of the app not 20% of the cost of your finished products. I don't know if your app can be free and still in the app store but from what you have written free would work since you will actually make your money on the goods. Just bill normally for the orders you receive